# extra spaces in my regex expressions

Tags: python, regex

okay so my in put data looks like this:

```
talk.politics.guns a:11 about:2 absurd:1 again:1 an:1 and:5 any:2 approaching:1 are:5 argument:1 etc...
```

and I want to binarize it and get an output like this:

```
talk.politics.guns a:1 about:1 absurd:1 again:1 an:1 and:1 any:1 approaching:1 are:1 argument:1 etc...
```

however, wen I run my code I'm somehow inserting and extra space after the colon:

```
talk.politics.guns a: 1 about: 1 absurd: 1 again: 1 an: 1 and: 1 any: 1 approaching: 1 are: 1 argument: 1 etc...
```

How do I get rid of this space?

heres my code:

```
import sys
import re

input_file = sys.argv[1]
input_file = open(input_file, 'r')

binary = re.compile(r"([:])([0-9]+)")
line = input_file.readline()

while(line):
    line = binary.sub(r"\1 1", line);
    print line
    line = input_file.readline()
```

Comment: Do not reuse variables like this: `input_file = open(input_file, 'r')`. It makes you code unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: There's a space before the 1 in the `sub()`. That's probaby the reason, right? ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this programming language but try to do something like this binary.sub(r"\1"."1", line);

Comment: Try: `line = binary.sub(r'\g<1>1', line)` instead of the current sub line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to capture the  `:` colon which exits just before to the digit.
 `(?<=:)` Positive lookbehind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a `:` . `\d+` would match one or more digits.

```
binary = re.compile(r"(?<=:)\d+")
line = input_file.readline()
while(line):
    line = binary.sub(r"1", line);
    print line
    line = input_file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind assertion and don't use a while loop to read a file:

```
import sys
import re

input_file = sys.argv[1]
with open(input_file, 'r') as input_file:
    binary = re.compile(r"(?<=:)\d+")
    for line in input_file:
        print(binary.sub(r"1",line))
```